# Rails3.1: Server for HTTP streaming on Windows 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, stream

According to [ActionController::Streaming documentation](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.1.1/ActionController/Streaming) it's necessary to use right server, with output flush/push support.

There is example for unicorn, but unicorn it's unix-only software.

Do you know any server, which I can use to run this on Windows 7?:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def test
    render :stream => true
  end
end
```

in view file:

```
SUPER<br/>
<% sleep 5 %>
SUPER 2<br/>
<% sleep 5 %>
SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be hard with most of the servers, as you mentioned some of them has limited support, so jruby may be your best option. [Kirk](https://github.com/strobecorp/kirk) may be good option for you. It's easy to use jruby wrapper for jetty. It supports both request and response streaming.